# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'title()'

Tags: python-3.x

```
first="harry"
last="potter"

print(first, first.title())
print(f"Full name: {first.title()} {last.title()}")
print("Full name: {0.title()} {1.title()}".format(first, last))
```

The first two statements works fine; which means there is attribute title() to 'str' object.
The third print statement gives error. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

The `str.format()` syntax is different from f-string syntax. In particular, while f-strings essentially let you put any expression between the brackets, `str.format()` is considerably more limited. [Per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> The grammar for a replacement field is as follows:
>
> ```
> replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
> field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
> arg_name          ::=  [identifier | digit+]
> attribute_name    ::=  identifier
> element_index     ::=  digit+ | index_string
> index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
> conversion        ::=  "r" | "s" | "a"
> format_spec       ::=  <described in the next section>
> ```

You'll note that, while attribute names (via the dot operator `.`) and indices (via square-brackets `[]`) - in other words, *values* - are valid, actual method calls (or any other *expressions*) are not. I hypothesize this is because `str.format()` does not actually execute the text, but just swaps in an object that already exists.

---

Actual f-strings (your second example) share a similar syntax to the `str.format()` method, in that they use curly-brackets `{}` to indicate the areas to replace, but according to [the PEP that introduced them](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/),

> F-strings provide a way to embed expressions inside string literals, using a minimal syntax. It should be noted that an f-string is really an expression evaluated at run time, not a constant value.

This is clearly different (more complex) than `str.format()`, which is more of a simple text replacement - an f-string is an expression and is executed as such, and allows full expressions inside its brackets (in fact, you can even nest f-strings inside each other, which is fun).

Answer (score 0):

***str.format()*** passes string object in respective placeholder. And by using '***.***' you can access the string attributes or functionalities. That is why ***{0.title()}*** searching for the specific method in the string class and it is getting nothing about **title()**.

But if you use

```
print("Full name: {0.title} {1.title}".format(first, last))

>> Full name: <built-in method title of str object at 0x7f5e42d09630><built-in method title of str object at 0x7f5e42d096b0>
```

Here you can see you can access built-in method of string

If you want to use ***title()*** with ***format()*** then use like this:

```
print("Full name: {0} {1}".format(first.title(), last.title()))

>> Full name: Harry Potter
```